# Is there a typo in the name of the "Joga Bounito" hat?

Tags: bug, status-completed, wording, winter-bash-2014

We have currently a hat called "Joga Bounito":

[image]

Bounito? Which language is that?

It is clearly a latin-derived language, so not English, German, Arabic, Chinese...

- In Portuguese it should be "Joga Bonito" (which means "Plays beautifully").
- I'm not sure about Spanish, but I guess that it should be then "Juega Bonito".
- I'm not sure about Italian either, but I guess that it should be "Gioca Bel".
- In French (not sure) it should be "Joue Beau".
- In Romen (really unsure) it should be "Joacă Frumos".

So, the best guess is that it is in Portuguese. Further this hat is basically a soccer ball, and in this year we had the FIFA World Cup in Portuguese-speaking Brazil, which is known for being a country where soccer is the main sport. So "Joga Bounito" would really be Portuguese.

But there is a small problem. It has a typo: It should not be "Bounito", it should be "Bonito".

Comment: Oops. I didn't hunt down the spelling before this hat was shipped. I'll see if we transfer the extra "u" to the British.

Comment: @JonEricson is it safe to assume that when we spin the [wheel of blame](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/show/light/) for Winter Bash 2014, it should always come up you?

Comment: @psubsee2003: The Wheel is fickle and unpredictable.

Comment: You surely spent lots of time and efforts on a bug report that could just say "there's a typo in [hat name here]". You deserve a bonus hat for that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now, it is fixed. :)

[image: Joga Bonito]