# I believe Joga Bonito should be named Jogo Bonito

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I just earned the [Joga Bonito](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/joga-bonito) hat, but I believe its name might be incorrect.

*Joga Bonito* is technically correct, but it means *to play beautifully*, while I suspect the implied meaning of the hat is *Jogo Bonito*, which means *the beautiful game* (*jogo* is a noun while *joga* is a verb).

It's uncommon to say *joga bonito* unless you are speaking about the way someone plays. While it's very common (in Brazil) to refer to football as *jogo bonito*, or the beautiful game.

So, which is it?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheElfHat It's not a duplicate. The other question has an issue with the word "bounito" which is an incorrect spelling of "bonito", or beautiful. Please retract that vote. The suggestion in the other question may still be wrong depending on the intended meaning of the hat.

Comment: Judging solely on your translations, I'd say either could fit in context.  Yes, they're different, but it seems like both could be correct in this situation.  Despite being the name of a hat (technically a noun) not all of the hat names are nouns, consider, for example, the "I voted today" hat.  It could mean that you "played beautifully" when you reviewed, or it could be referring to the review system as a whole as "the beautiful game".

Comment: @Servy yeah, true, but I feel that's stretching it a bit. In would expect a hat with a football to be about, well, football itself. Also, many non-Portuguese speakers who visit Brazil make that mistake. But what the heck. Maybe it's not that important in the end.

Comment: Can the downvoters please explain why they are downvoting? Is this not a legitimate question? And did the close voters actually read both questions to see that there is a difference, even if it's subtle?

Comment: OK, I've now edited it to make it really different from the typo bug report. Voted to reopen as well. :)

Comment: Thanks @gnat for the final vote!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We did some research since our [initial mistake](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245303/is-there-a-typo-in-the-name-of-the-joga-bounito-hat) and [our resident expert](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/08/introducing-gabe-the-smiling-community-manager/) says that *Jogo Bonito* is the correct translation, but *Joga Bonito* sounds cooler and is more relatable. Apparently, Nike has a [marketing campaign](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0U_e-juHPY) built around the phrase. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beautiful_Game#Terms_used):

> Nike began using the slogan *Joga bonito* in a campaign preceding the 2006 FIFA World Cup in an attempt to curb players behaviours on the pitch. In collaboration with, and promoted by, former international footballer Eric Cantona, Nike released a series of adverts to promote a game that is skillful and dignified, not riddled with theatrics and poor sportsmanship.

Since the hat is awarded based on activity in the review queue, where we want fair play, this phrasing seems appropriate to me.