# What consitutes a duplicate question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I asked [this question yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245491/is-joga-bonito-written-correctly-i-think-not), and it was marked as [duplicate of this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245303/is-there-a-typo-in-the-name-of-the-joga-bounito-hat). Although it's clear to me, and those who read both, that the questions are different.

My question--[correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245501/153274)--raised to issue the meaning of the phrase *joga bonito*, while its purported original pointed out the incorrect spelling of the word *bounito*.

So my question is about language usage (*joga*, a verb, versus *jogo*, a noun), while the original is about a spelling mistake (*bounito* should be spelt *bonito*).

Is there something I am missing about the definition of a duplicate question? The help center states the following:

> The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people
>   find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place. ...
>   There are many ways to ask the same question, and a
>   user might not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a
>   different way.

It's obvious that the two questions are different. And why would mine warrant several down votes, while the purported original garnered 17 up votes? Is it so different to point out that usage *might* be incorrect?

Comment: It's a delicate matter that happens a lot on meta site: two questions having the same answer are duplicates, even if they are different. I know it's confusing, but that's how meta works.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't see how the answer on the purported original is the same as the answer to my question. The earlier says "It's fixed." If anything the one on my question explains the rationale: While my definition is correct, SE thinks that its current form sounds cooler and is more relatable.

Comment: "Spelling of 'bonito' is fixed" is not the same as "*jogo* is correct, but we think *joga* is more relatable".

Comment: Fair enough, voted to reopen.

Comment: see also: [Using duplicates as answers on Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188410/165773) and [Does the new guidance on duplicate questions suggest closing a question as duplicate, if the original answers the OP's question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217401/165773)